# Linq Grouping by a list of a list and selecting from both lists

Tags: c#, linq

So I'm having trouble wrapping my head around Group By currently for Linq and in essence am looking to grab the id from Pirate and all information within Ships, Ideally thrown into a list of IEnumerable DataRow (DataRow got hidden..).

```
public class Pirate
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public List<Ship> Ships { get; set; }
    }
    public class Ship
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ShipClass { get; set; }
        public string AvastyMast { get; set; }
    }

static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Pirate> Pirates = new List<Program.Pirate>();

        Pirate Arr = new Pirate();
        Arr.Id = "1";

        Ship Pinta = new Ship();
        Pinta.Name = "Maria";
        Pinta.ShipClass = "BattleShip";
        Pinta.AvastyMast = "You Sunk My BattleShip";

        Ship Manta = new Ship();
        Pinta.Name = "Clara";
        Pinta.ShipClass = "Scout";
        Pinta.AvastyMast = "You Sunk My BattleShip!";

        Arr.Ships.Add(Pinta);
        Arr.Ships.Add(Manta);

        Pirates.Add(Arr);

        Pirate Sid = new Pirate();
        Sid.Id = "2";

        Ship Nuclara = new Ship();
        Pinta.Name = "Boon";
        Pinta.ShipClass = "Sub";
        Pinta.AvastyMast = "You Sunk My BattleShip!!";

        Ship Nutella = new Ship();
        Pinta.Name = "Slimer";
        Pinta.ShipClass = "Scout";
        Pinta.AvastyMast = "You Sunk My BattleShip!!!";


    }
```

So what I would like to do is Have a list of DataRows via Linq from the above, so that if I go through each DataRow and wrote out each row and column it would produce the following.

```
1 , Maria, BattleShip, You Sunk My Battleship
1 , Clara, Scout, You Sunk My Battleship!
2 , Boon, Sub, You Sunk My Battleship!!
2, Slimer, Scout, You Sunk My Battleship!!!
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What is the input and what is the expected output?

Comment: `grab the id from Pirate and all information within Ships, Ideally thrown into a list of IEnumerable.` what?

Comment: You code does not compile. `class` is a reserved keyword. Are these private fields? Or should they be public properties?

Comment: Made some small edits, sorry for the confusion,  I just threw the two classes up there as an example of the objects i'm dealing with.  Will throw more edits in momentarily.

Comment: What fields should the `DataRow` contain?

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: Any particular reason you need the output to be a DataRow?

Comment: Output ideally in DataRows as I'll be bulkinserting the results into a database using SqlBulkCopy.

Comment: So the code that does the bulk insert requires the input to be data rows?

Comment: Never mind, just looked up SqlBulkCopy, I guess getting data rows is the easiest for you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var pirates = new List<Pirate>(); // or wherever your pirates will come from

var data = from p in pirates
           let pirateId = p.Id
           from s in p.Ships
           select new
           {
               PirateId = pirateId,
               Name = s.Name,
               Class = s.ShipClass,
               AvastyMast = s.AvastyMast
           };
```

If you really want to get `DataRow` objects out of it, you can create a small method to create the `DataRow`:

```
private static DataRow CreateDataRow(DataTable table, string pirateId, string name,
    string shipClass, string avastyMast)
{
    var row = table.NewRow();

    // Make sure the column names match those in the table!
    row["PirateId"] = pirateId;
    row["Name"] = name;
    row["ShipClass"] = shipClass;
    row["AvastyMast"] = avastyMast;

    return row;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var pirates = new List<Pirate>(); // or wherever your pirates will come from
var dataTable = new DataTable(); // or wherever your DataTable will come from

var data = from p in pirates
           let pirateId = p.Id
           from s in p.Ships
           select CreateDataRow(dataTable , pirateId, s.Name, s.ShipClass, s.AvastyMast);
```

Comment: Yes, this one makes sense assuming he does not really need data rows.

Comment: Problem is that it's from a list of pirates (My fault for the bad formatting of the quesiton initially).

Comment: @IvanS Why is that a problem?  The query will work fins in `pirates` is a collection of `Pirate` objects.

Comment: You guys are 100% spot on, got confused as I was using pirates in the second from instead of p, and couldn't access ships.  Going to verify one or two things but will likely be marking this as the answer.

Comment: Yup this worked, (also realized my real life example has another list to get data from...) but applied the same results and it appears to be working properly..

In essence I just added another from and drew from that  as well,  though now i'm a little paranoid..

Comment: Paranoia unneeded, I understand it now.  Let is technically unneeded though right?   Irregardless marking as answer, thanks everybody for the patience and swift assistance!

Comment: @IvanS Right, the `let` is technically unneeded. Glad to be of help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Pirate> pirates = new List<Pirate>() {
                    new Pirate() { id = "1" , Ships = new List<Ship>(){
                        new Ship() { name = "Maria", _class = "BattleShip", avastyemast = "You Sunk My Battleship"},
                        new Ship() { name = "Clara", _class = "Scout", avastyemast = "You Sunk My Battleship"}
                    }
                },
                    new Pirate() { id = "2" , Ships =  new List<Ship>() {
                        new Ship() { name = "Boon", _class = "Sub", avastyemast = "You Sunk My Battleship"},
                        new Ship() { name = "Slimer", _class = "Scout", avastyemast = "You Sunk My Battleship"}
                    }
                }
            };

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("class", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("avastyemast", typeof(string));

            foreach (Pirate pirate in pirates)
            {
                foreach(Ship ship in pirate.Ships)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(new string[] {
                        pirate.id,
                        ship.name,
                        ship._class,
                        ship.avastyemast
                    });
                }

            }


            //using linq
           var newRows = pirates.Select(x => x.Ships.Select(y => new List<object>() {x.id, y.name, y._class, y.avastyemast})).SelectMany(z => z).ToList();
           foreach (var row in newRows)
           {
               dt.Rows.Add(row);
           }
        }
    }
    public class Pirate
    {
        public string id {get;set;} 
        public List<Ship> Ships {get;set;}

    }
    public class Ship
    {
        public string name {get;set;}
        public string _class {get;set;}
        public string avastyemast {get;set;}
    }
}
​
```

Comment: This way works and was mostly the original way I thought of doing it, though I feel like it's might be more efficient using Linq. Thank you though for a more optimized version of my backup plan.

Comment: Added your data to the example